# String match with a list of regex and add column to give the corresponding value if match Python

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I'm having trouble to find string match in one column df with another df with a list of regex and its own regex type. This is the regex df.

```
 **Country** |  **Regex**

     CN      |  ^\w{8,25}$
     BE      |  ^BE[0-9]{10}
     AT      |  ^ATU[0-9]{8}
```

Then, I want the value in the Data column in another df to scan and find any match with the regex df and return its own country type where they found the match regex. This is the output that I want (the Suggestion column). Need it to give me the suggestion which country type that match the regex.

```
 **Data**   | **Suggestion**            **Data**   | **Suggestion** 

 BE135688   |              ---->        BE135688   |   BE   
 78567899   |                           78567899   |   CN
 AT5678899  |                           AT5678899  |   AT
```

This is what I've tried,

```
df['Data'].str.match(df_regex.Regex)
```

But I got this error,

```
TypeError: ("'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed", 'occurred at index 271179')
```

I know the str.match can only match with string type. But I don't know how to make it scan over the whole value in the column and return its own country type for the matching regex. Is there any better way to do this? Appreciate the helps :)

Comment: No expert here. But you can convert the dataframe to string using df.astype(), because it says dataframe series is immutable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to loop over all regexes and, each time there is a match, add the corresponding country to the suggestions. Here is an example*:

```py
import pandas as pd
df_regex = pd.DataFrame({'Country': ['CN', 'BE', 'AT'],
             'Regex': ['^\w{8,25}$', '^BE[0-9]{10}', '^AT[0-9]{7}']})
df = pd.DataFrame({'Data': ['BE135688', '78567899', 'AT5678899']})
regex_map = dict(zip(df_regex.Regex, df_regex.Country))
def country_suggestions(row):
    matches = []
    for reg in regex_map:
        if re.search(reg, row):
            matches.append(regex_map[reg])
    return ', '.join(matches)

df['Suggestions'] = df['Data'].apply(country_suggestions)
print(df)
```

This is the output:

```
        Data Suggestions
0   BE135688          CN
1   78567899          CN
2  AT5678899      CN, AT
```

*Notice I've changed the regex `^ATU[0-9]{8}` to `^AT[0-9]{7}`, so it actually matches the value `AT5678899`. That should be adjusted appropriatelly.